# Use case where script filenames have leading numbers to determine execution order

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, filesystem

I'm looking for documentation or a use case where in Linux there is a directory with shell scripts where each filename is led with a number, and the files are run in that particular order. What is this convention called, and where is it used?

For example:

```
0001-motd.sh
0002-proxy.sh
0300-ssh.sh
```

I know I have seen this before, just not sure where or what it is called.

Comment: Are you thinking of the runlevel scripts that are in `/etc/rc?.d` directories?

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you are referring to `run-parts`

```
NAME
       run-parts - run scripts or programs in a directory

SYNOPSIS
       run-parts  [--test]  [--verbose] [--report] [--lsbsysinit] [--regex=RE]
       [--umask=umask] [--arg=argument] [--exit-on-error] [--help] [--version]
       [--list] [--reverse] [--] DIRECTORY

       run-parts -V

DESCRIPTION
       run-parts  runs  all  the  executable  files  named  within constraints
       described below, found in directory directory.  Other files and  direc‐
       tories are silently ignored.

       If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then
       the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters,
       ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.

       If  the  --lsbsysinit  option  is given, then the names must not end in
       .dpkg-old  or .dpkg-dist or .dpkg-new or .dpkg-tmp, and must belong  to
       one  or more of the following namespaces: the LANANA-assigned namespace
       (^[a-z0-9]+$);   the   LSB   hierarchical   and   reserved   namespaces
       (^_?([a-z0-9_.]+-)+[a-z0-9]+$);  and  the  Debian cron script namespace
       (^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$).

       If the --regex option  is  given,  the  names  must  match  the  custom
       extended regular expression specified as that option's argument.

       Files  are  run  in  the  lexical  sort order (according to the C/POSIX
       locale character collation rules) of their names unless  the  --reverse
       option is given, in which case they are run in the opposite order.
```

Comment: Yes. It's used in a lot of places. Old SysV init files (in `/etc/rc.*`), network-manager auxiliary scripts, `X11` startups, suspend-resume procedures....

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, either this method/hack will work or not for your case. But, I think this will work If I got you right.

```
[feddy@localhost ~]$ mkdir test
[feddy@localhost ~]$ cd test
[feddy@localhost test]$ ls
[feddy@localhost test]$ vi 0001-ko.sh
[feddy@localhost test]$ cp 0001-ko.sh 0002-ko.sh
[feddy@localhost test]$ cp 0001-ko.sh 0004-ko.sh
[feddy@localhost test]$ cp 0001-ko.sh 0005-ko file.sh
[feddy@localhost test]$ cp 0001-ko.sh 0008-ko.sh
[feddy@localhost test]$ ls
0001-ko.sh  0002-ko.sh  0004-ko.sh  0005-ko file.sh  0008-ko.sh

[feddy@localhost test]$ for i in *
> do
> bash "$i"
> done
file 0001-ko.sh
file 0002-ko.sh
file 0004-ko.sh
file 0005-ko file.sh
file 0008-ko.sh
[feddy@localhost test]$
```

**OR**

```
$ find . -iname "*.sh"|while read f; do bash "$f"; done
file ./0001-ko1.sh
file ./0002-ko1.sh
file ./0005-ko1 file.sh
file ./0005-ko1.sh
```

You can make a script and use it to execute scripts in order (according to numbers which included in the filename i.e xxxx-abcdef ) in any folder.

Please correct me If I got you wrong.

Comment: @steeldriver, oh sorry, If the filename will contain spaces then this code doesn't work correctly. Sorry again for my mistake, I am going to update it.
Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the sort order of glob matches (if enabled) follows the locale collation setting.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, yeah I also think so.

Comment: Anyone, who is willing to downvote any answer on StackExchange sites, at least tell the author, what mistake he did, So from on next time, he will make sure that same thing won't happen again. **Because** it takes lots of time and effort to write a proper answer for others.

And, Downvoters just need to click a down arrow, that's all.

Comment: I didn't vote on this answer, but the question asks for documentation - "or what is this called?", not a script to do it.